# How to calculate the number of operations in this function?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, runtime, big-o

So my friend gave me the f(n), but I don't understand how he got there. Would like some info on how. We are essentially learning how to write algorithms with big O notation. The problem is just counting work assignments within the code and nested loops are each N intervals. I just don't understand where the division comes from in this case.

```java
public static String[] sum4(int N)
{
    //DO NOT COUNT IN opCount
    long opCount = 0;
    String fn = "f(N) = 5N+5(N(N-1)/2)+4";
    String On = "O(N) = n^2";
    //BEGIN opCounts
    long sum = 0;
    opCount++;// assignment of sum
    opCount++;//assignment of i
    opCount++;//comparison of I < N
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        
        opCount++;//assignment of j
        opCount++;//comparison of j < i
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)//5N
        {
            sum++;
            opCount+=2;// sum addition and assignment
            opCount+=2;// J++ addition and assignment
            opCount++;// Comparison of J < I and the multiplier
        }
        opCount++;// I < N comparison
        opCount+=2;// I++
    }
    opCount++;//return
    return new String[] {fn, On, opCount+""};
}
```

Comment: Hi @hyperspacewoo. Can I kindly remind you to mark solutions as answer in your both previous questions and this particular question? Marking your questions as answered will encourage SO users to answer your other questions in future.

Answer (score 1):

First analyze the total number of operations performed in the innermost loop:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)//5N
  {
    sum++;
    opCount+=2;// sum addition and assignment
    opCount+=2;// J++ addition and assignment
    opCount++;// Comparison of J < I and the multiplier
  }
```

`sum addition and assignment` --> 2 operations 
 `J++ addition and assignment` --> 2 operations
`Comparison of J < I and the multiplier` --> 1 operation
In total, it takes 5 operations in each loop. So how many loops are there? There are `i` many loops. To calculate the number of operations dependent on `n`, now we have to examine outer loop:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        
        opCount++;//assignment of j
        opCount++;//comparison of j < i
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)//5N
        {
            sum++;
            opCount+=2;// sum addition and assignment
            opCount+=2;// J++ addition and assignment
            opCount++;// Comparison of J < I and the multiplier
        }
        opCount++;// I < N comparison
        opCount+=2;// I++
    }
```

`//assignment of j` --> 1 operation 
`//comparison of j < i` --> 1 operation 
inner for loop --> 5 * `i` many operations (we calculated it above) 
`// I < N comparison` --> 1 operation
`// I++` --> 2 operation
Therefore in **one** iteration, it performs `5 + 5*i` many operations. To sum up:

```
Total operations = (5 + 0) + (5 + 5) + (5 + 10) + (5 + 15) + ... + (5 + 5*(N-1))
                     i=0       i=1        i=2        i=3               i=N-1
Total operations = 5*N + 5*(0 + 1 + 2 + .. + (N-1))
Total operations = 5N+5(N(N-1)/2)
```

Now, add the last assignments:

```
 // assignment of sum
 //assignment of i
 //comparison of I < N
 //return
```

In total, there are 4 many operations.
Total number of operations: `5N+5(N(N-1)/2)+4`

Comment: It's not explicit in the post, but it's fairly clear that the author was using `opCount` as a sort of external count, and isn't including it in the algorithm or its runtime. See, e.g. `//DO NOT COUNT IN opCount
    long opCount = 0;` and the fact that no operations on `opCount` are treated as having cost. So most of this answer appears to count something that the author was not intending, and gets to the final formula by coincidence.

Comment: Your edited analysis is now correct. The statement 'Every time he increments the opCount variable, it actually increments the number of operations' is precisely the mistake I was referring to before. In OP's accounting, an operation like `sum++` costs two operations, and `opCount++` costs zero. However, your original analysis redefined these all to start costing one to make the math work out to the same result as OP's formula. Now that all statements like `i++ --> 1 operation` in your original post have been edited to match OP, i.e. `// I++ --> 2 operation`, the derivation is valid

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the division in the term 5N+5(N(N-1)/2)+4, it comes from the fact that you execute the lines in the innermost loop N(N-1)/2 times.
In each iteration of the outermost loop, you will execute the innermost loop `i` times. So when `i` is 0, you  will execute the inner loop 0 times, when `i` is 1, you will execute the inner loop 1 time, when `i` is 2, inner loop 2 times, and so on...
In total, the number of times you execute the inner loop is 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N-1, and that sum is equal to N*(N-1)/2.
Here is some background on how the sum is evaluated to its closed-form: https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/

Comment: Where does the division come from though. I understand the N-1

Comment: It is just a fact that 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N-1 = N(N-1)/2. So if you understand why the inner loops runs 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N-1 times, then you also understand why it runs N*(N-1)/2 times. That's just because of the identity. If you want to understand why the identity holds, and ultimately why you need the division, the link gives an excellent proof of why that is the case. Or search for something like 'Sum of the First n Positive Integers'